# How can I create the days property in a DateInterval extension class?

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I want to extend the `DateInterval` class to add my own methods. For this I want to create an instance of the `DateIntervalEx` extension class from a `DateInterval` object.
Example:

```
$dateInterval = date_create('yesterday')->diff(date_create('today 13:24'));

$diEx = new DateIntervalEx($dateInterval);
```

My attempt for the class:

```
class DateIntervalEx extends Dateinterval{
  public function __construct(DateInterval $interval){
    parent::__construct('P0D');

    foreach($interval as $prop => $value){
      $this->$prop = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

The `diff()` method returns a `DateInterval` with `$days == 1`

```
DateInterval::__set_state(array(
   'y' => 0,
   'm' => 0,
   'd' => 1,
   'h' => 13,
   'i' => 24,
   's' => 0,
   'f' => 0.0,
   'weekday' => 0,
   'weekday_behavior' => 0,
   'first_last_day_of' => 0,
   'invert' => 0,
   'days' => 1,
   'special_type' => 0,
   'special_amount' => 0,
   'have_weekday_relative' => 0,
   'have_special_relative' => 0,
))
```

But my extension class returns days => false.

```
DateIntervalEx::__set_state(array(
   'weekday' => 0,
   'weekday_behavior' => 0,
   'first_last_day_of' => 0,
   'days' => false,
   'special_type' => 0,
   'special_amount' => 0,
   'have_weekday_relative' => 0,
   'have_special_relative' => 0,
   'y' => 0,
   'm' => 0,
   'd' => 1,
   'h' => 13,
   'i' => 24,
   's' => 0,
   'f' => 0.0,
   'invert' => 0,
))
```

How can I set the days property to the correct value?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days: _“[days] If the DateInterval object was created by DateTime::diff(), then this is the total number of days between the start and end dates. Otherwise, days will be FALSE.”_

Comment: Even if I replace the content of your constructor function with just `parent::__construct($interval->format('P%yY%mM%dDT%hH%iM%sS'));`, the result stays the same - `days` in the resulting object is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do on PHP.

The `$days` property is set by the PHP runtime if the `DateInterval` was created using `DateTime::diff()`, as you probably saw on the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

> days
>
> If the DateInterval object was created by DateTime::diff(), then this is the total number of days between the start and end dates. Otherwise, days will be FALSE.
>
> Before PHP 5.4.20/5.5.4 instead of FALSE you will receive -99999 upon accessing the property.

Check how two important `DateTime` extension projects deal with this (e.g. they don't):

Chronos ([`ChronosInterval`](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos/blob/3ff9eb5a81654770893843b542b767636c122187/src/ChronosInterval.php#L218) extends `DateTimeInterval`):

> ```
> /**
>  * Create a ChronosInterval instance from a DateInterval one.  Can not instance
>  * DateInterval objects created from DateTime::diff() as you can't externally
>  * set the $days field.
>  *
>  * @param \DateInterval $di The DateInterval instance to copy.
>  * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
>  * @return static
>  */
> public static function instance(DateInterval $di): self
> {
>    if (static::wasCreatedFromDiff($di)) {
>        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
>            "Can not instance a DateInterval object created from DateTime::diff()."
>        );
> }
> // ...
> ```

Carbon ([`CarbonInterval`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/32f184cf27d00e41f99021b2a1fbcc5abe713976/src/Carbon/CarbonInterval.php#L862) extends from `DateTimeInterval`)

> ```
> /**
>  * Create a CarbonInterval instance from a DateInterval one.  Can not instance
>  * DateInterval objects created from DateTime::diff() as you can't externally
>  * set the $days field.
>  *
>  * @param DateInterval $interval
>  *
>  * @return static
>  */
> public static function instance(DateInterval $interval)
> {
>     return self::castIntervalToClass($interval, static::class);
> }
> ```

You can check the relevant C code [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6e2cd97b4368e888193819dc0a6d1306b219ec21/ext/date/php_date.c#L2036).

Comment: I guess I have to accept that. Thanks for the detailed answer.